# Azure Personalizer model updating issue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on a requirement where I am using Azure Personalizer. I created a console application and took the code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/personalizer/quickstart-personalizer-sdk?pivots=programming-language-csharp. I have set the configuration settings `Reward wait` time to 10s and `Model update frequency` to 1 min and `Evaluation percentage` to 20%. After running my application I was asked to choose what time of day it was and what is my taste preference a/q to that they recommend, but when I choose "no" it is not able to re-train the model and still it is showing the same recommendation.
Can anyone help me with the above issue?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: I have taken example from the below link https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/tree/master/dotnet/Personalizer

Comment: Please [edit] your post with _your_ code, not someone else's code. You want to make a [mre].